# Passing an entire sql query as a parameter in jasper reports

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports

I want to pass an entire sql query as a parameter into a jasper report. I tried using $P{QUERY}, but it gave me a mysql syntax error exception. And I want it to be passed during run time. Does anyone know how to do it?

Example code:

```
try {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.getInstance().getConnection();

        map.put("QUERY", "Select u.name, u.status from user_info u where u.user_name = 'Thanuj'");

        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("report1.jrxml");
        JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map, conn);
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jp, false);
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReportTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReportTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ReportTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: `"it gave me a mysql syntax error exception"` ... What is "it"?  I used Jasper reports for many years and never came across a use case where I needed to pass a raw SQL query.  Why are you doing this?  Can you explain more?

Comment: I used report query window to add the parameter (Dragged and Dropped) Then it gave me a mysql syntax error exception. I' using iReport designer. Exception occurred from mySql.

Comment: I figured out the answer. I will post it as an answer to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer with some help from my colleague. I had to change the parameter ($P{QUERY}) into ($P!{QUERY}) in the jasper report's xml file (ex; report.jrxml)

[image]

Comment: It should work, since I used this method to pass quires and it worked flawlessly, can you be more descriptive and explain what you exactly did? what difficulties you encountered?

Comment: after two days, I figure out  that i should put ($P{QUERY}) without ! in jasper xml file and .... with ! in crosstable   ($P!{QUERY})  , thank you